# Can I connect Zoiper to GOIP?

Tags: call, voip, voip-android

I used GOIP to send SMS from my application. Sometime, client call to this phone number but they cannot connect because I didn't config Income Call on GOIP.
Is it possible to connect Zoiper application (Android) to GOIP without Call Center Gateway?

http://www.hybertone.com/en/pro_detail.asp?proid=10
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zoiper.android.app&hl=en&gl=US

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

No you can't! GOIP is an UAC as Zoiper as UAC too.